# Animating CALayer of UIView to round corners

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, rounded-corners, catransition

I'm trying to animate the rounding of the corners of my view.  The cornerRadius property is listed as animatible, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I actually can't get any of the other properties to animate either, but the corners are what I'm interested in.  Here's my code, and it's pretty darn simple:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];

self.myView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0f;

[CATransaction commit];
```

What am I missing here guys?  The corners become rounded, but it's instantaneous instead of taking 2 seconds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
CABasicAnimation *anim1 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
anim1.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
anim1.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
anim1.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0f];
anim1.duration = 2.0;
[self.myView.layer addAnimation:anim1 forKey:@"cornerRadius"];
```

Comment: where is this code located? in viewDidLoad? or viewWillAppear? or viewDidAppear?

Comment: It's the action of a button press.

Comment: see above for new, improved answer

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4.2/5**:

```
let anim1 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
anim1.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
anim1.fromValue = 0
anim1.toValue = 50
anim1.duration = 2.0
layer.add(anim1, forKey: "cornerRadius")
```

**Swift 3/4.0**:

```
let anim1 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
anim1.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
anim1.fromValue = 0
anim1.toValue = 50
anim1.duration = 2.0
myView.layer.add(anim1, forKey: "cornerRadius")
```

**Update:**

As Mark noticed, it's cleaner to use `#keyPath` to describe the property to be animated:

```
let anim1 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.cornerRadius))
```

Comment: #keyPath(CALayer.cornerRadius) would be slightly better.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're overthinking it. I was able to get by without using CoreAnimation. Here's what I did:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
    self.myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
}
```